Schedule Alarm Alert in Google Play store
Your app schedules exact alarms without checking whether the SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission has been granted. This is causing your app to crash for users on Android 14 because the permission is no longer granted by default.
In most cases, alternative methods of scheduling work or inexact alarms are more appropriate. If your use of exact alarms is justified, update your app so that it checks this permission is granted before scheduling.
Getting this above error in google play store using these permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />

how to resolve this error

So does your code try to check whether SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM has been granted? That looks like it would be the next thing to do...

@JonSkeet yes so how can i do it in react native before call schedule function?

It sounds like your answer is really "no" rather than "yes" - and I have no idea how you would do it, but that's the next thing you should research.

But about 20 seconds of searching found https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid, so I'd start there...

I think this can work by adding permission to user
